# returnで生成されたはずのチェックボックスが作動しない。

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

最初の行にUITextFieldとチェックボックスを表示して、UITextFieldでreturnキーを押した時に、次の行に新しいUITextFieldとチェックボックスが表示されるようなプログラムを作りたいのですが、UITextFieldはいまくいったもののチェックボックスが作動しません。どうすれば作動するのでしょうか。
以下、親クラス、子クラスの順番となっています。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var firstBox: UIButton!

var newBox: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var firstTextField: UITextField!

var counter = 0

var newTextField: UITextField!

var currentTextField: UITextField!

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    counter += 1
    createNewTextFieldAndBox(parameter: counter)
    return true
}

func createNewTextFieldAndBox(parameter: Int)
{
    //information of the textfields
    let tWidth = Int(firstTextField.frame.width)        //250
    let tHeight = Int(firstTextField.frame.height)      //30
    let XofTextField = Int(firstTextField.frame.origin.x)
    let YofTextField = (Int(firstTextField.frame.origin.y) + 16)*parameter + 20

    //information of the boxes
    let bWidth = Int(firstBox.frame.width)
    let bHeight = Int(firstBox.frame.height)
    let XofBox = Int(firstBox.frame.origin.x)
    let YofBox = (Int(firstBox.frame.origin.y) + 16)*parameter + 20

    //create new TF
    newTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: XofTextField, y: YofTextField, width: tWidth, height: tHeight))
    self.view.addSubview(newTextField)
    currentTextField = newTextField
    currentTextField.delegate = self

    //create new Box
    newBox = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: XofBox, y: YofBox, width: bWidth, height: bHeight))

    newBox.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "uncheckedBox"), for: .normal)
    self.view.addSubview(newBox)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    firstTextField.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

以下、子クラスです。

```
import UIKit

class CheckBox: UIButton {
var isChecked:Bool = false
{
    didSet
    {
        if isChecked == true
        {
            self.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "checkedBox"), for: .normal)
        }
        else
        {
            self.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "uncheckedBox"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib()
{
    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttondClicked(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    self.isChecked = false
}

func buttondClicked(_ sender:UIButton)
{
    if(sender == self)
    {
        if isChecked == true
        {
            isChecked = false
        }
        else
        {
            isChecked = true
        }
    }
}
}
```

一部インデントがおかしくなっているところがあるかもしれませんがご容赦ください。また、子クラスのawakeFromNib以下やその周辺のコードはネットから引っ張ってきたものをほぼコピペしただけのものなので、あまりコードの意味がわかっていない状況です。ここのあたりのコードも新しいチェックボックスが作動しないことと関係あるのでしょうか。

Comment: 「チェックボックスが作動しません」と言うのは、「画面上の所望の位置には追加されるが、チェックボックスとしての動作が行われない」と言うことでよろしいでしょうか?

Comment: サブクラス`CheckBox`を定義、実装していますが、`ViewController`クラスで、一切使われてませんね？

Comment: @OOPer その通りです。説明不足で申し訳ありません。

Comment: @nagonsoftware 元々はfirstBox newBoxともにcheckboxクラスに属するようなコードにしていたのですが、自分で色々いじってみたところ、checkboxをuitextfieldに変えても作動しています。同様なチェックボックスを使った他の試作品でも問題なく作動しました。自分でもよう分かっていない状況です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

表示されているチェックボックスが動作しない理由は2点あります。

- チェックボックスとしての動作は`CheckBox`に実装されているのに、ただの`UIButton`をインスタンス化している
- `CheckBox`クラスでは`awakeFromNib()`により、チェックされた時のactionを指定しているが、普通のコンストラクタでインスタンス化すると`awakeFromNib()`が呼ばれない

と言うわけで、修正点としては、

チェックボックスとして使いたいボタンは`CheckBox`と宣言しましょう:

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstBox: CheckBox!

var newBox: CheckBox!
```

Nib(.xibや.storyboard)からインスタンス化しないのであれば、明示的に`awakeFromNib()`を呼んでやりましょう:

```
    //create new Box
    newBox = CheckBox(frame: CGRect(x: XofBox, y: YofBox, width: bWidth, height: bHeight))
    newBox.awakeFromNib() //<-

    newBox.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "uncheckedBox"), for: .normal)
    self.view.addSubview(newBox)
```

と言うことになります。

普通は部品として公開するようなコードについては、上記2点目のような注意はしなくて良いようにするものなのですが、あなたが参照されたコードは実用的と言うよりかなり実験的なものですね。本当は書き換えたい部分がいっぱいあるのですが、本質的では無いのでここでは遠慮しておきます。

上記2点の修正を行ってみて、まだ何か思うように動作しない点があれば、コメント等でお知らせください。

Comment: 完璧に動きました。まだ初心者なので、実用的、実践的といったニュアンスの違いがまだしっくりのこないのですが、教えていただいたコードの意味を理解しつつ、ビギナー脱却目指して頑張ります。ありがとうございました。

Comment: iOSのリマインダーアプリのようなUIデザインは、iOSの標準部品を組み合わせるだけでは実現できないので、初心者の方には少々ハードルが高いですね。[同じようなUIデザインを`UITableView`を使って実現しようとされている方のご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/34443/13972)がありましたので、ご参考までに。こちらもテーブルビューの使い方など一通りのことは把握していないといけないので、それなりにハードルは高いですし、あれこれ迷っていろんなやり方をごちゃまぜにしてしまうのもまずいのですが、詳細は後回しにして、こんなやり方もあるんだ、と言うのは知っておかれると良いかもしれません。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。勉強になります。